# jquery date time picker is not working in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am adding Jquery library and put in datetimepicker from using jquery, not working and weird layout.
i want use inline datetimepicker like below:

[image]

but not working .
when i run my code,

[image]

MY source code is below

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <h2>Column 2</h2>
    <input type="text" id="datetimepicker3" />
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    format: 'd.m.Y H:i',
    inline: true,
    lang: 'ru'
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the [jquery.datetimepicker.css](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css)

Please add it inside the head tag like,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.css" />
```